# How to made multiple LineChart in WPF Dynamic Data Display?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, d3.js

I have 3 collection in c# (wpf application). I need to show them a line chart graph. I researched too much websites and i only have dynamic data display d3. so i tried to make a chart as below in wpf.

[image]

i found a code from stackoverflow but i couldnt make it as i thought. i can only show one line in the field and it can only show as below.

[image]

and my another problem is horizontal axis. How can i make horizontal values as string or as [10-2016]. Here is codes i found.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:d3="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Research.DynamicDataDisplay;assembly=DynamicDataDisplay"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <d3:ChartPlotter>
            <d3:LineGraph DataSource="{Binding Data}"></d3:LineGraph>
        </d3:ChartPlotter>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
MyViewModel viewModel;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            viewModel = new MyViewModel(); 
            DataContext = viewModel;
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            double[] my_array = new double[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < my_array.Length; i++)
            {
                my_array[i] = Math.Sin(i)*3;
                viewModel.Data.Collection.Add(new Point(i, my_array[i]));
            }

        }
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableDataSource<Point> Data { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Data = new ObservableDataSource<Point>();
    }
}
```

Is there any easy way to make chart as upper picture. I dont know anything about wpf charts and i dont have any budget to pay wpf chart libraries. I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Did you check the oxyplot library? http://www.oxyplot.org/ It's a very nice library made for WPF. It might be easier to use than d3.

Comment: @Gimly i tried oxyplot. But i didnt find any tutorial about this. So i couldnt make it. It doesnt matter any library i only want to solve my problem.

Comment: Your requirement is really easy to do with Oxyplot, but I agree with you that the documentation is a bit lacking. The easiest to get started is to go to https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/tree/master/Source/Examples and check the examples. Don't hesitate to clone the oxyplot repo and check all the code, it's pretty easy to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you use Live Charts.

Each line on the graph is represented by a 'LineSeries' and it is designed to be MVVM friendly. It's 100% free, and you can install using NuGet.

[Live Charts](https://lvcharts.net/)

[How to install](https://lvcharts.net/App/examples/v1/wpf/Install)

Example:

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <lvc:CartesianChart Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}" LegendLocation="Right" >
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
            <lvc:Axis Title="Sales" LabelFormatter="{Binding YFormatter}"></lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
            <lvc:Axis Title="Month" Labels="{Binding Labels}"></lvc:Axis>
        </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    </lvc:CartesianChart>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public SeriesCollection SeriesCollection { get; set; }
    public string[] Labels { get; set; }
    public Func<double, string> YFormatter { get; set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
        {
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Series 1",
                Values = new ChartValues<double> { 4, 6, 5, 2 ,4 }
            },
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Series 2",
                Values = new ChartValues<double> { 6, 7, 3, 4 ,6 },
                PointGeometry = null
            },
            new LineSeries
            {
                Title = "Series 3",
                Values = new ChartValues<double> { 4,2,7,2,7 },
                PointGeometry = DefaultGeometries.Square,
                PointGeometrySize = 15
            }
        };

        Labels = new[] {"Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May"};
        YFormatter = value => value.ToString("C");

        //modifying the series collection will animate and update the chart
        SeriesCollection.Add(new LineSeries
        {
            Title = "Series 4",
            Values = new ChartValues<double> {5, 3, 2, 4},
            LineSmoothness = 0, //0: straight lines, 1: really smooth lines
            PointGeometry = Geometry.Parse("m 25 70.36218 20 -28 -20 22 -8 -6 z"),
            PointGeometrySize = 50,
            PointForeground = Brushes.Gray
        });

        //modifying any series values will also animate and update the chart
        SeriesCollection[3].Values.Add(5d);
    }
}
```

Output:
[image: Line Series graph]