# WPF - Multiple Graphs with Shared Axes

Tags: c#, wpf

We have requirement to display multiple graphs sharing common x axis as shown in the below figure.
We are searching for the NuGet packages using which we can implement the above requirement.

Please suggest the packages providing the sharing x axis feature. We are developing desktop application with WPF.

We tried with Scott Plot but it didn't yield appropriate results.

[image]

Comment: I think the problem is, that you are searching for the wrong thing. Its is ONE graph, not multiple graphs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41049410/9272708

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to made multiple LineChart in WPF Dynamic Data Display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048977/how-to-made-multiple-linechart-in-wpf-dynamic-data-display)

Comment: thanks for your suggestions but we have to create 80 graphs in one form & we will segregate into 5 segments(16 graphs per segment) & display each graph line by line. We tried to put all data in one graph with different colors but all have similar data & it is overlapping & not appealing while viewing.

Comment: I agree with @RatzMouze. You don't need more than one chart for this. You can show multiple data on a single chart. I use the open source ScootPlot in my projects and I am very satisfied. You can check it here. https://github.com/ScottPlot/ScottPlot

Comment: @ashveli okay. But you still have a range of data. When you pull the data, you got to have a min and max value for dates for example, so maybe i dont understand you correctly, but the range will be the same, across your your List<objects>, no? Then they would automatically have the same x axis, no?

Comment: please use the image(4 plot lines) attached in question as reference & let me know if it is possible to do same as it is with Scott Plot. If we use 1 graph and plot 16 lines, they will be overlapped (although different colors). They all have same date range as x-axis.

Comment: @ashveli something else you could do, is to add checkboxes, to toggle what data to show in the single graph, because 80 graphs are gonna be just as unappealing.

Comment: @RatzMouze,yep that is also there in our requirements.

Comment: we have used Scott Plot & implemented as you said but the graph is not coming nice, so we have decided to do as per the image(instead of 4, there will 16)

Comment: so these 80 graphs are segregated into 5 segments/columns, each segment has 16 & these 16 graphs have time as x-axis and it is common.

Comment: @ashveli You are very unclear in explaining this, and it makes it difficult to help you. As i understand you now, you have 5 graphs, with 16 lines/functions in each, where the functions should be displayed like the the picture?

Comment: yes exactly, please help. is it possible in Scott Plot or any other packages, as you suggested in other answer we are considering live charts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This is scichart](https://www.scichart.com/example/wpf-chart/wpf-chart-example-vertically-stacked-yaxis/), this should be what you are looking for.

With this, you are able to separate the functions in your chart, by the y Axis only.